# Android RTSP Live Streaming Issue

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, rtsp, vitamio

Android Video Live Streaming Problem
 I am using Vitamio library. The RTSP streaming is working well, Now I want to record that RTSP live streaming in my SD card locally. please help !!!

```
Or can i use media recorder to record RTSP live streaming ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Recorder is not the good way to record RTSP video, I have used the FFMPEG library to record RTSP recording locally in sd card.
Steps to do this.

1. Capture or decode the RAW frames from live stream and pass them to ffmpeg and save them to sdcard in .h264 format.
2. Then again pick .h264 raw file and decode the file using ffmpeg, and save the file with extention .mp4 into sd card.
3. delete the .h264 file programmatically, and save only .mp4, or which format you want.
4. Try .mp4 playback.

I am able to record long time such as upto 5mb video's into my sd card.

Comment: give me your mail address

Comment: Hi I have done the streaming of the rtsp live stream through videoview and it works fine. Can you please share your code of how to save the rtsp stream to sdcard.

Comment: @Deepak Yeah I also want to know. Can you share code?

Comment: send me email at kdeepak5477@gmail.com